# Magento2 : How to check a product is available in Store Using SKU

Tags: magento2, product

I am able to updated the product price and Quantity. before that i wanted to check if `product is available in store or not`.

Here is the code of updating Price and Stock.

```
public function updateProduct($product_id, $price, $qty1){

       ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
       $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
       $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
       $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
       $storeId = '1'; //Store ID

       $productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

       $product = $productFactory->create();
       $prduct_id_sku = $product->load($product->getIdBySku($product_id));

       $oldprice = $product->getPrice();
       $productName = $product->getName();

       $oldstock = $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId());

       if (($oldprice != $price) || $oldstock != $qty1 ) {

          $product->setPrice($price); 

          if ($oldstock != $qty1) {
            $product->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                    'qty' => $qty1 ));   
        $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $qty1, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
          }else{
            //echo " \n oldStock & new stock are equal ".$qty;
         }
         $product->save();

        }else {
          //echo " \n oldprice & new price are equal ".$price;       
        }
        unset($storeIds, $websiteObj, $_websiteId);
        unset($product);
        }
```

Please guide me. if there is no product available with SKU 
what will be in

```
$prduct_id_sku = $product->load($product->getIdBySku($product_id));
```

`$prduct_id_sku` will be `null` or not. I was not able to debug to test this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line.

```
    $prduct_id_sku = $product->load($product->getIdBySku($product_id));
    $oldprice = $product->getPrice();
    $productName = $product->getName();
    $oldSku = $product->getSku();
    if ((($oldprice != $price) || $oldstock != $qty1) && !$oldSku) {
        $product->setPrice($price);
        if ($oldstock != $qty1) {
            $product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                'manage_stock' => 1,
                'is_in_stock' => 1,
                'qty' => $qty1 ));
            $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $qty1, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
        } else {
            //echo " \n oldStock & new stock are equal ".$qty;
        }
        $product->save();
    } else {
        //echo " \n oldprice & new price are equal ".$price;
    }
    unset($storeIds, $websiteObj, $_websiteId);
    unset($product);
}
```

Comment: by adding this like `&& $oldstock` if condition, When i have product listed and stock has reduced to zero, then it is not updating the value. Any idea how to recognize available product with 0 stock.?

Comment: Replace getStockQty()  on getIsInStock()

Comment: This i got `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockState::getIsInStock() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service.php on line 113`

Comment: This need get from a product ( you can use product->getQty(),  getIsInStock)  From product.

Comment: Example `&& product->getQty()  == 0`

Comment: Oh sorry, me))) You need `product->getSku() `

Comment: I am updated answer.

Comment: I have compared with price as price will always be positive value`&& $oldprice`

Comment: Please,  do it,  as I saw)

Comment: You will have true & &  true if $oldSku = null,  or 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78458/discussion-between-jb-pakalapati-and-evgeniy-kapelko).